# How can I move all `marked` files to another directory in ranger?

Tags: mv, file-manager, move, ranger

When I select multiple files within ranger (using `<Space>` or `V`), how do I move these selected files to another directory?

I've tried to use `dd` and `pp`, but this only moves the file that's currently highlighted.

Comment: I've found one way, using the ":cut" and ":paste" commands. I was looking specifically for a keybinding though.

Comment: `dd` is bound to `cut` by default - so `dd` should do what you want. Check your keybindings with `?k`

Answer (score 30):

With the files / directories marked, press `dd`, then navigate to the directory you want to paste them in and press `p`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. As soon as I hit `d` it opens a sub-menu, which I can't seem to do anything with.

Answer (score 12):

- use `space` to mark files i.e "toggle=true"
- use `yt` to yank files flagged as "toggle=true"
- enter the directory you want
- use `pp` to paste toggled files
- use `dt` instead of `yt` to cut instead of copy

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Hitting `space` seems to add a space to the front of the filename. Hitting `y` opens up a submenu that I can't seem to work.

Comment: After that submenu opens you press `t` to carry out the action.